# Add constraints to tables in Sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I am adding constraints to tables in Sqlite as following:

```
alter table TagsI18N
add constraint FK_TagsI18N_TagId foreign key (TagId) references Tag(Id) on delete cascade on update cascade,
    constraint FK_TagsI18N_LanguageCode foreign key (LanguageCode) references [Languages](Code) on delete cascade on update cascade;
```

I was using this code in SQL Server database but is not being accepted in SQLite.

How can I create such a constraint in Sqlite?

Comment: What is the error you get? (An obvious error is the usage of `[..]` which is illegal in standard SQL for an identifier - maybe SQLite doesn't like them either)

Answer (score 2):

The ALTER command in SQLite3 is limited to adding columns or renaming tables, so you cannot do this.  Instead, you must re-create the table with the desired constraints.